# Calling MeasureItem procedure (TMenuItem, Delphi)

Tags: delphi, menuitem

I have this procedure, it is a `TMenuItem` event (Miscellanous – `OnMeasureItem`). It works properly.

```
MeasureItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas; var Width, Height: Integer);
```

I would like call it in a `FormResize` event, but I receive the "Not enough actual parameters" message.

Can you help me how can I call it correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call it. It gets called automatically when the menu needs  to get the size of the  item for the menu as it's being built to display. May I ask why you think you need to call it manually?

Comment: You aren't supposed to call this event. It is called by the system when it wants to display a menu. Before displaying the menu the system  has to work out how much space is needed for all the menu items. It does so by calling this event. Your error is because you aren't passing enough parameters, just as the compiler says. The way to fix it is to pass the right parameters. But I'm sure you don't want to call it at all.

Comment: In the FormResize event I did this:

if Form1.Label55.Font.Color =clNavy then
   Form1.Width:=1000 else
if Form1.Label55.Font.Color =clBlack then
  Form1.Width:=700;

I would like that the width of the Menu become larger too after changing the font colour.
But it rests the same, and I don’t know how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: Menus don't work like that; menu size is not a changeable setting. If you're wanting to change the behavior, you need to owner draw the menu (draw each item yourself). And menu **width** changes automatically when the form width changes - I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do now. For instance, start Notepad (or WordPad, or any other Windows app that has a menu), and make the window wider or narrower; the **menu** width changes, but the **item** width doesn't - the `File` menu is the same width no matter how wide the form.

Comment: Why are you implementing OnMeasureItem? Surely the system can work out the size needed for the menu?

Answer (score 1):

"Not enough actual parameters" means you haven't provided all the parameters it expects. That method requires four parameters. The first should be a reference to the menu item being measured, the second should be a canvas containing the attributes that would be used for drawing the menu, if the menu were really being drawn, and the remaining parameters should be variables that will receive the requested size of the menu item.

That's *how* to call the method. Whether you *should* call the method is another matter entirely. I invite you to post another question about that topic if you need to.